# how can i manage, received USSD codes in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ussd

I'm new developer of android with Eclipse,i have a problem with USSD codes.

how can i read received USSD codes by my app? for example, if user send *123# , the answer from operator just read by app and user never see it, also app can read all of ussd code contents and manage that.

just tell me how can i do this, if i can read USSD codes, i can manage it with my app.

Comment: Since Android 4.2.2, an API to intercept USSD is removed. Read [this issue on AOSP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57120) for more information.